# Best C++ RTP/RTSP library

Tags: c++, udp, sip, rtp, rtsp

I'm looking for a RTP/RTSP library in C++. I found [pjsip](http://www.pjsip.org) but it is more C-style. I'm looking for more OO library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[JRTPLIB](http://research.edm.uhasselt.be/jori/page/CS/Jrtplib.html) is very nice, and used in well-known projects such as SightSpeed (and lots of little ones).  Pretty well-designed, very flexible license; pretty easy to get things right with it.

Comment: It doesn't support RTSP though

Comment: Here's a lib that supports RTSP and used JRTP to support RTP and RTCP https://github.com/Ansersion/myRtspClient

Comment: ccRTP also seems solid https://www.gnu.org/software/ccrtp/

Answer (score 73):

Check [live555](http://live555.com) Useful libraries and code examples of how to stream stuff from your own app. The repo is full of RTP, RTSP, and SIP code examples and libraries.

Comment: not sure why their sample only worked for mp3 files that too very slow  and during fast/forward it cannot cope up.

Comment: i worked on making live555 efficient. the deeper i went the more crappy the software structure looks. when it's moving along bytes of a frame to parse it, it keeps making recursive calls. awful software engineering